# Computing values for R dataFrame cells without using for loops

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataFrame with the followings:

```
Serial N         year         current    Average 
   B              10            14          15
   B              10            16          15
   C              12            13          12
   D              40            20          20
   B              11            15          15
   C              12            11          12
```

I would like to have a new column based on the average for a unique serial number. I would like to have something like :

```
Serial N         year         current    Average      temp 
   B              10            14          15        (15+12+20)/15
   B              10            16          15        (15+12+20)/15
   C              12            13          12        (15+12+20)/12
   D              40            20          20        (15+12+20)/20
   B              11            15          15        (15+12+20)/15
   C              12            11          12        (15+12+20)/12
```

temp column is the addition of the average value for each Serial N ( for B,C and D) over the value of the average for that row. How can I computing it without using for loops as rows 1,2 and 5 (Serial N: B) is the same in terms of Average column and temp? I started with this:

```
for (i in unique(df$Serial_N))
   {
       .........
    }
```

but I got stuck as I also need the average for other Serial N. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use library `dplyr` and grouping to achieve what you want. But, it is not clear to me how you are getting those numbers (15 + 12 + 20) / 15. Can you update the question to reflect the right values from input data?

Comment: 15 is the Average for Serial N (B), 12 is the average for Serial N (C) and 20 is the Average for Setial N (C) and the /15 is the Average for that Serial N (B)

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can try something like the following (assuming your computation matches):

```
df$temp <- sum(tapply(df$Average, df$SerialN, mean)) / df$Average
```

Resulting output:

```
  SerialN year current Average     temp
1       B   10      14      15 3.133333
2       B   10      16      15 3.133333
3       C   12      13      12 3.916667
4       D   40      20      20 2.350000
5       B   11      15      15 3.133333
6       C   12      11      12 3.916667
```

Comment: I think he means `sum(unique(df$Average)) / Average` (assuming averages aren't repeated between different groups...there are more thorough ways)

Comment: What happen if I would like to get access to Average (for each unique Serial N)?

Comment: `sum(tapply(df$Average, df$Serial_N, unique)) / Average`, maybe, though there's got to be a simpler way.

Comment: Based on the update and clarification, I agree. It is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Using `unique.data.frame()` can avoid repeat in `Average` between different groups

```
df$temp <- sum((unique.data.frame(df[c("Serial_N","Average")]))$Average) / df$Average
```

Comment: Nice use of `unique`! You don't really need to specify the `.data.frame` method, though, as that's what will get called anyway if you pass it a data.frame. Also, you should probably have a `,` before `c(...` to show you want all the rows; it works as-is, but it's good to be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use either

```
df <- transform(df, temp = sum(tapply(df$Average, df$Serial_N, unique))/df$Average)
```

or

```
df$temp <- sum(tapply(df$Average, df$Serial_N, unique))/df$Average
```

both of which will give you

```
df
#   Serial_N year current Average     temp
# 1        B   10      14      15 3.133333
# 2        B   10      16      15 3.133333
# 3        C   12      13      12 3.916667
# 4        D   40      20      20 2.350000
# 5        B   11      15      15 3.133333
# 6        C   12      11      12 3.916667
```

`tapply` splits `df$Average` by the levels of `df$Serial_N`, and then calls `unique` on them, which gives you a single average for each group, which you can then `sum` and divide. `transform` adds a column (equivalent to `dplyr::mutate`).

Comment: What happen if I would like to get access to Average (for each unique Serial N)? Since there are identical, how can I access each  (Serial N B,C, and D) ?

Comment: That's what the `tapply` gives you; you can index the result to get a single average. Or use Reese's `unique(df[,c("Serial_N","Average")])` if you like.

Comment: I get your point, thank you. But  let me may be rephrase what I mean, I would like to use each of the Average (unique) as input for another function (I do not want to use loop through  each of them as I have about 10000 distinct Serial N each having an Average. I can get unique Serial N and Average using what you mentioned, but how can I use each Average without loops (use each of them as an input to another function)?

Comment: Save the results of `tapply` or whatnot to a variable, and pass that variable as the input. Or pass the `tapply` directly. You can almost always pass a vector of values in R; there's no need for loops for such purposes.

Comment: I did this: temp=unique(df[,c("Serial_N","Average")]) , then I did this temp$new_set=tapply(temp$Average, function(x) { 2 * pnorm(x * sqrt(2)) - 1} ). So for each value (unique of Average), I would like to apply that function. I got the erro: r error in unique.default(x) unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: That's not how `tapply` works; it splits a vector for levels of a second factor. Also, you're conflating data.frames and columns, so I can't really see what you're trying to do. It's probably time to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thanks